# Java - How to get OS logged-username (from domain)?

Tags: java, windows, authentication, tomcat

I need some help with the following scenario.

1. Imagine a end-user receives an email (on its desktop) with a link to a web application. That app I've built in Java and it's running on top of a Tomcat servlet in another dedicated machine. That workstation the user is logged on authenticates against a Domain Controller (active directory).
2. I've seen many commercial applications that also runs on top of tomcat and that somehow bind themselves to Microsoft IIS/AD, so that when an end-user access their app, they can get the domain-user logon and single-sign-on them into that built Java application. Long story short, I gotta do the same

But where to start? All I know is that currently I'm not being able to do so, since

**System.getProperty("user.name");** is not working since it gets the user that is authed against the app. But it's **not** the case right now. **What I need is to get the auth user of the OS**

- So should I bind my Java to Tomcat and have my that last one to be bind against IIS/AD ?
- Or somehow I can make my Java app bind directly to IIS and get that OS logged user?

Thanks a lot, Bruno Oliveira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scenario you mentioned above question is called "**Single Sign on**"

You can't get user info logged on a desktop with Web Application alone.

to implement single sign on you need three components namely Active Directory , Single Sign on Component and your Web Application

i hope you can refer this article on [IBM  developer works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-singlesign/) to implement on your own.
apart from these there are many tools and commercial components available in market
I hope this will help you..!